# Access schema value in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Dataset - Contains PostId and userID

```
20    1
21    2
45    3
85    1
48    1
98    1
74    1
96    2
63    2
33    3
44    3
55    3
66    3
77    3
```

I want to access the userID with maximum no. of post

PIG code

> A = load '/home/cloudera/Desktop/post.txt' as (postid:chararray, userid:chararray);
>
> B = load '/home/cloudera/Desktop/user.txt' as (name:chararray, id:chararray);
>
> C = group A by userid;
>
> D = foreach C generate group,COUNT(A.postid) as count;
>
> E = order D by count DESC;
>
> F = limit D 1;

It gives output  -

> (3,6)

Now what should be the PIG statement to access username from user.txt whose id is same as A.userid after execution of F statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another statement to get the first column from relation F

```
G = FOREACH F GENERATE $0;
DUMP G;
```

Comment: How can we access the "userid" value in the other statements like say for FILTER condition @inquisitive

Comment: @AkashTyagi I am not sure what your question is.If you have a question please ask another question with sample data,script you have tried and the desired output.

Comment: Perhaps like this B = FILTER A BY (userid == 3) ?

Comment: Use join G = JOIN F BY F.$1,B BY B.id; DUMP G;

Answer (score 0):

use the below SQL statement to get that desired output

```
declare @var int = (select max(cn) from (select count(post) cn from temp group by userid) c)    
select * from (select userid,count(post) as pso from temp group by userid ) as c where pso = @var
```

Comment: what can be the equivalent PIG statement for it.